# Problema ao criar função de busca em C

Tags: c

A função buscar recebe o endereço do primeiro elemento de uma lista (p) e uma cadeia de caracteres (subnome). Supondo que subnome `Francisco` do nome da pessoa `matheus francisco` vai me retornar-lo ao invés de `NULL`. Estou com dificuldades para fazer funcionar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_NOME 50

typedef struct pessoa
{
     char nome[MAX_NOME];
     int idade;
     char subnome[MAX_NOME];
}Pessoa;

/*celula lista*/
typedef struct Lista{
    Pessoa *elemento;
    struct Lista *prox;
}celula;

typedef celula *Lista;
void inserir(celula *ptr, Pessoa *p){
    if( ptr == NULL){
             printf("Lista vazia ");
        return 0;
    }
  celula *novo;
  novo = malloc(sizeof(celula));
  novo->elemento= p;
  novo->prox = ptr->prox;
  ptr->prox = novo;

}
celula *inserir_inicio(celula **topo, Pessoa *p ){
     celula *novo;
  novo = malloc(sizeof(celula));
   novo->elemento= p;

  if(*topo == NULL){
    novo->prox = NULL;
    *topo = novo;
    return novo;
  }
  else{
  novo->prox =*topo;
  *topo=novo;
  return novo;
}
}
celula *remover_ini(celula *topo)
{
    celula *lixo = topo;
        if(lixo == NULL)
        {
            printf("Lista vazia");
        }
        else
        {
            topo = topo->prox;
            printf("Elemento a ser excluido: %c", 10);
            printf("Nome: %s | Idade: %d \n",lixo->elemento->nome, lixo->elemento->idade);
            free(lixo);
        }
    return topo;

}
void remover(celula *topo){
    if(topo->prox == NULL){
        celula *aux;
        aux = topo->prox;
        free(topo);

    }
    celula *lixo;
    lixo = topo->prox;
    topo->prox = lixo->prox;
    free(lixo);
}
void Busca(celula *topo, char sobnome[]) {
     celula *aux;
      aux = topo;
      while(aux != NULL)
        {
            if(aux->elemento->subnome)
             printf("%s", aux->elemento->subnome);
      aux = aux->prox;
      }

}
void printar(celula *topo){
 celula *aux = topo;
  if(aux == NULL)
  {
    printf("vazio");
  }
  else{
      do{

         printf("Nome: %s | Idade: %d \n",aux->elemento->nome, aux->elemento->idade);
             printf("-------------------------- \n");
         aux= aux->prox;

      }while(aux != NULL);
  }
}



main()
{
  Lista topo = NULL;
  Pessoa p1,p2,p3,p4,p;
  Pessoa *info_removida;
  int menu = 1;

    p1.idade = 30;
    strcpy(p1.nome, "matheus " );


    p2.idade = 18;
    strcpy(p2.nome, "mayara");

    p3.idade = 19;
    strcpy(p3.nome, "juca");

while ( menu != 0) {
        printf(
        "\n-----------------------------------------------------\n"
        "Selecione opcao que deseja, veja nosso menu:\n"
        "-----------------\n"
        "0 - Sair \n"
        "1 - Inserir no Inicio\n"
        "3 - exibir \n"
        "2 - Inserir \n"
        "4 - Remover \n"
        "5 - Remover fi\n"
        "6 - Para buscar pessoa sobnome\n"
        "-----------------\n"
        "0 - SAIR DO PROGRAMA.\n"
        "-----------------\n"
        );
        scanf("%d", &menu);
        switch (menu){

            case 0:
                printf("Voce fechou.");
            break;
            case 1:

                inserir_inicio(&topo, &p1);
                inserir_inicio(&topo, &p2);
                inserir_inicio(&topo, &p3);

            break;

             case 2:
                 inserir(topo, &p1);

            break;
            case 3:

                printar(topo);
            break;
            case 4:
              topo = remover_ini(topo);
           break;
            case 5:
                remover(topo);
                break;
            case 6:
                Busca(topo);
             break;
            default:
                printf("Opcao inexistente.");
                break;
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Encontrei dois problemas, quando passas `topo` para função `Busca` estás a passar a copia da variavel em vez do seu indereço. Devias dar também uma olhadela na função `strstr` http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função de `busca` precisa receber além da lista um `sobnome` que falta passar como parâmetro na hora em que chama ela.

E se a sua intenção é que ela retorne `NULL` tem que mudar o tipo do retorno para um ponteiro e receber o mesmo e tratá-lo na `main`:

**Busca:**

```
celula *Busca(celula *topo, char sobnome[])
{
        celula *aux = topo;
        celula *achado == NULL;
        while(aux != NULL)
        {
                if(strcmp(aux->elemento->subnome, sobnome) == 0)
                        achado = aux;
                aux = aux->prox;
        }
        return achado;
}
```

**Declaração na `main`:**

```
main()
    {
      Lista topo = NULL;
      Lista encontrado = NULL;
      Pessoa p1,p2,p3,p4,p;
      Pessoa *info_removida;
      int menu = 1;
```

**Chamada da função `busca`:**

```
 case 6:
       encontrado = Busca(topo, "Francisco");
 break;
```

Dessa forma a função busca vai retornar a `celula` que contém o sobrenome ou `NULL` se o mesmo não existir, basta você fazer o tratamento que lhe convir.

Comment: if(strcmp(aux->elemento->subnome, sobnome) == 0)
                        achado = aux;
                aux = aux->prox; esta tando um erro nesse codigo !! strcmp

Comment: É na hora de compilar? Qual é o erro?

Comment: pessoa has no member named "subnome"                                                                 mas eu fiz essa funcao 
celula *Buscar(Lista lst, Pessoa x){
    celula *p = lst->prox;
    while ((p != NULL) && (p->elemento->sobnome != x.nome)){
        printf("%s",p->elemento->sobnome);
        p = p->prox;
    }
    return p;
} e rodou imprimiu só q dps não imprime mais e buga o programa

Comment: A `pessoa` realmente não tem `sobnome` que você está tentando acessar aqui `(p != NULL) && (p->elemento->sobnome != x.nome)`. `Pessoa` tem `subnome`. Se é que não alterou a `struct pessoa`.